# How to iterate and return each value continuously in a list?

Tags: python, pygame

So I am trying to draw a rainbow in python using Pygame. I would like to avoid using the `random.randint(0,255)` method for each RGB value. I have already made a list containing the RGB values of a rainbow in Python. I am trying to iterate over this list and return each value continously so that these colors can be fed into pygames parameter when drawing a circle. `pygame.draw.circle(window, color, radius=5)`.

My code:

```
rainbow = [VIOLET, INDIGO, BLUE, GREENS, YELLOW, ORANGE, RED]
def iterate(list):
  while True:
    for i in list:
      return i

print(iterate(rainbow))
```

However, the output only returns the first value of `VIOLET`, which is `(148, 211,0)`.

Comment: It returns `VIOLET` only, because you return it, which stops the function from executing. You're saying you want to call the function multiple times, and get each list item in order each time you call the function? Does it need to start over, or end, when it gets to `RED`? Have you considered just using an index, and incrementing that, to get subsequent list values, rather than using a function? If you really want to use a function, it seems like a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean "continuously in a list"? Lists are container objects in Python that hold a variable number of other objects.

Answer (score 1):

Use yield:

```py
rainbow = [VIOLET, INDIGO, BLUE, GREENS, YELLOW, ORANGE, RED]
    def iterate(list):
        for i in list:
          yield i
    
print(iterate(rainbow))
```

Yield turns this into a generator statement, which is basically what it looks like you want. I'm not sure why the `while` loop was there, but you won't need it.
I hope this is what you needed.

Comment: You cannot just `print()` an iterator object to get a value, you need to use `next()` on it. Also there is a built in function `iter()` which turns a sequence (like a list) into an iterator so no need to reimplement it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want a function which can be used in loops to forever cycle through the colors of the rainbow. So create an infinite iterator:

```
from itertools import cycle

rainbow = cycle([VIOLET, INDIGO, BLUE, GREENS, YELLOW, ORANGE, RED])
```

Now you can use `next(rainbow)` to always get the next color. After `RED` you will start from `VIOLET` again.

Example:

```
col = next(rainbow)   # returns VIOLET
cols = [ next(rainbow) for i in range(2) ]   # returns [ INDIGO, BLUE ]
for col in rainbow:
    print(col)   # this will be an infinite loop as rainbow never runs out
```

Answer (score -1):

Your return i means return i and exit immediately.

Can you not move print in your iterate func?
Alternatively concatenate all colours and finally return the value.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to infinitely iterate through each, convert to a generator:

```py
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def gen(data):
    it = iter(data)
    while (True):
        try:
            yield next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            it = iter(data)

generator = gen(data)
while (True):
    print(next(generator))
```

Comment: thank you so much this works. I basically needed it to return each time and this was the perfect solution thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :)